# javascript Regex unicode help

Tags: javascript, regex, unicode

in a JavaScript, i am using Regex to `split(/\W+/)` to words.

when i split this, it's returning wrong value

```
var s3 = "bardzo dziękuję";
s3 = s3.split(/\W+/);


[0]: "bardzo"
[1]: "dzi"
[2]: "kuj"
```

How to fix this problem? please advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex isn't splitting because it is treating your accented characters as non-word characters.

Use the whitespace special character:-

```
s3 = s3.split(/\s+/);
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case, why not just split with whitespace?

`s3.split(/\s+/);`

Answer (score 1):

You could use CharFunk https://raw.github.com/joelarson4/CharFunk , which handles Unicode fully.

```
var s3 = "bardzo dziękuję";

function notLetterOrDigit(ch) {
    return !CharFunk.isLetterOrDigit(ch);
}

CharFunk.splitOnMatches(s3, notLetterOrDigit);
```